# Shortcut key not working: Option + s

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

I need to type the eszett or scharfes S (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) and the shortcut combo key is Option + s. However, nothing happens when I type said combination; not even a cursor movement, but I can type most other special characters like §, ç, Œ, etc. Most google search results confirm that it is indeed Option + s. I also checked my ownkeyboard settings but can't seem to find the fix. Any help or ideas, please?

macOS X Sierra

Comment: Double check that somehow this has not been set as the shortcut for Text to Speech or something similar in the preferences for Speech/Dictation/Accessibility.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the tip, I carefully checked out the locations you mentioned and had no luck, sadly. Still, I'm grateful for your suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Temporary fix can be [type-leftwards-arrow-on-macos](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369800/type-leftwards-arrow-on-macos/369803#369803)