# Type leftwards arrow on macOS

Tags: keyboard, mojave

I need to type a leftwards arrow, an example as follows:

[image: arrow]

Is this possible using the keyboard on macOS Mojave?

Comment: What I do is I use [aText](https://www.trankynam.com/atext/) and I use abbrebiations that start with `!a-`, like `!a-right`, `!a-down`, which then expand to the unicode arrows. At least for me this was the best way to effortlessly throw in arrows because the abbreviations are easy enough to remember: [here's a gif of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdrKF.gif) — I thought that maybe you could use the built-in text expander, but I think it has some limitations that make it unusable in general. That's how I remember it anyways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to bring up the **Character Viewer**. It is also accessible in edit menu → Emoji and Symbols. Leave the cursor where you want to type and double click on the arrow you want.

[image]

Alternatively, The **alt codes** for arrows can be viewed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)) on Wikipedia. Have Hex input enabled and active in input sources in keyboard preferences.

[image]

For right arrow, hold alt and type 2190. ← will appear.

> [image]

<sup>Source:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrows_(Unicode_block)</sup>

More standard codes can be found in this table

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Standardized_subsets

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways you can do this:

## Copy and paste the character

You can simply copy and paste the unicode 2190 character

## Another method

1. In System Preferences, click Language & Region
2. Click Keyboard Preferences
3. Click Input Sources
4. Click the + button
5. Scroll to the bottom of the list and select Other
6. Select Unicode Hex Input and click Add
7. Select Show Input menu in menu bar (if not already selected)
8. Close the System Preferences window

### To enter Unicode

1. Click the flag icon in the menu bar*
2. Select Unicode Hex Input
3. Hold down the option key while typing the Unicode Hex code:
   2190 = ←
   2192 = →
   2191 = ↑
   2193 = ↓

Answer (score 0):

You can [configure MacOS to replace key sequences](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh35735/14.0/mac/14.0) with other text. For example, to make it convert "<-" to "←":

1. Open **System Settings**
2. Go to **Keyboard** > **Text Replacements**
3. Press the **+** button and enter:

   - **Replace**: "<-"
   - **With**: "←" (enter with emoji dialog or copy from somewhere else)

If when typing you want to keep the two characters separate, you can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> after the conversion. Or use a different string in the **Replace** field, like "<--".

[image: Screenshot of System Settings dialog, showing where to find the Text Replacements button]

[image: Screenshot of the Text Replacements dialog, showing example replacements]