# Activating more type accents on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, internationalization

I have MacBook Pro and using Mojave currently.

I would like to add more type accents to my standart U.S. Q keyboard(or at least find an easy way to type 2 characters from my mother-tongue(Turkish). I have added my language to Input Sources from keyboard settings but no luck.

Is it possible to activate more type accents? (I only need these characters  though : g -> ğ, s -> ş)

Comment: [Type leftwards arrow on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369800/#369803) I answered this along the lines of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse a diacritic illiterate here. From the Wikipedia page of [Diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), I landed upon [Breve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve) , [Ğ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%9E) and [Cedilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla), [Ş](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9E) on Wikipedia.

### Unicode Values

- Ğ U+011E and ğ U+011F
- Ş U+015E and ş U+015F

**How to add Unicode Input on Mac**

Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Input sources and use the `+` for adding *Unicode Hex Input* having the symbol `U+`. Since you're here, check the box, *Show Input menu in menu bar*.

**How to type the characters**

If your Input source is not U+, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for changing the same. Holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> after lifting space bar shows the list of all added keyboards.

Given the Unicode values, hold <kbd>alt/option</kbd> and type the characters after `U+` one by one, sequentially. For e.g. hold <kbd>alt</kbd>, press 0, 1, 1, E. This types latin G with breve.

Unicode Keyboard is not so great, for me it stops me from jumping, deleting word by word. So <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> for reverting.

Find things like arrows, boxes or currencies on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Standardized_subsets

### Or Character Viewer

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to summon the **Character Viewer**. It is also accessible in the Edit menu → *Emoji and Symbols* in most apps. Leave the cursor where you want to type the text and type in the search bar of the popup, "Breve" or "Cedilla". You'll see some characters that support this. You can also add them to Favourites

[image: Character Viewer]

### Or Text replacement

You can set up a replacement in Keyboard Preferences → Text for S being replaced with Ş. Then in supported apps or utilities, like Safari, or spotlight, you'll see this:

[image: Replacement]

Thus I feel if you type Ş more, this is the easiest. Similar for other characters.

Comment: This will help, but I was looking for a solution that allows me to write Ş as easy as Ś and Š.

Comment: Try Text replacement, you'll get a choice between S and Ş in supported apps.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to type Turkish is to use one of the Turkish input sources supplied by Apple.  Make sure you have the Turkish flag showing in the top right corner of the screen (just adding it to Input Sources preferences is not enough).  To see which key does what, use the [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/10.14/mac/10.14).

Another way is to add the input source called ABC Extended to the list of Input Sources and then select that in the "flag" menu at the top right of the screen.  You can find the codes for all the letters you need [here](https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/).

You can pretty easily add your extra characters to unused keys on the US layout (or add brackets, etc to the Turkish layout) with [Ukelele](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele).

It may be possible to add characters to the Press/Hold popup menu of the US keyboard.  For info on that see [this earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion).

Comment: Then I will lost access to brackets etc.
If there is no possibility to add my 2 letters next to G and S, Ctrl+Space (or Ctrl+Cmd+Space) will be the easiest solutions. @ankii, if you add this solution as answer, I will accept it as a solution.

Comment: @Melih If you use the ABC Extended layout all the brackets, etc are preserved.  But I also added two other options in case they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's "ABC Extended" (US) keyboard layout has these accents on active 'dead keys' (`OPT-v` and `OPT-m`, if I see it correctly. You can check in `Keyboard viewer`.

I'm on Catalina, not sure this keyboard layout existed in Mojave – if not you could try installing my somewhat modified version at [GitHub](https://github.com/jokuha/keyboard-layouts).